# Proving $2X^5 -10X+5$ is irreducible.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to prove that $f(X)=2X^5 -10X+5$ is irreducible and the book that I'm following says that this is given by Eisenstein's Criterion. The problem is that I don't know how to use Eisenstein with a polynomial that is not monic. I thought dividing by $2$ but that gives  $5/2$ that I don't know how to work with.

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion isn't restricted to monic polynomials. The important condition on the leading coefficient is that it isn't divisible by the prime you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for using Eisenstein's criteria you just need to find a prime $p$ which divides all the coefficients apart from the leading coefficient of the polynomial and $p^2$ doesn't divide the constant term...there is no restriction on the polynomial being monic or not. As such, for your problem $p=5$ does the job.